# Interaction term significant, joint hypothesis not

Tags: econometrics

I am trying to find out if some channel is important in the transmission of shock x1 to outcome variable y.
For this, I am running a regression in which y is on the LHS and x1 on the RHS, once alone and once interacted with a variable x2 that differentiates between observations where the channel can exist and where it cannot.
I am getting that the interaction term is significantly different from zero, but when I test whether beta_x1+beta_interaction*[mean of x2]=0, I get that the H0 is not rejected, and when I test whether beta_x1=0, that is also not rejected.
What would you suggest, should I conclude that the channel is important on the basis of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at what you wrote, your regression has the form:
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,i} + \beta_2 x_{1,i} x_{2,i} + \varepsilon_i
$$
Here $x_2$ is a dummy taking the value $1$ for a subsample of observations and $0$ otherwise.

Then:
$$
E[y_i|x_{1,i} = x_1, x_{2,i} = 0] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1}.
$$
and
$$
E[y_i| x_{1,i} = x_1, x_{2,i} = 1] = \beta_0 + (\beta_1 + \beta_2) x_{1}.
$$

There are various hypothesis that you can test:

1. $H_0$: there is no (mean) effect of $x_1$ on $y$ for the subset where $x_{2} = 0$. This amounts to a test of $\beta_1 = 0$.
2. $H_0$: there is no (mean) effect of $x_1$ on $y$ for the subset where $x_{2} = 1$. This amounts to a test of $\beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$.
3. $H_0$: the (mean) effect of $x_1$ on $y$ is the same for the subsets where $x_2 = 1$ and $x_2 = 0$. This amounts to a test of $\beta_2 = 0$.

> I am getting that the interaction term is significantly different from zero,

This is a test of point 3. that the (mean) effect is different for the two subgroups.

> when I test whether beta_x1+beta_interaction*[mean of x2]=0, I get that the H0 is not rejected

You should not multiply $\beta_2$ with the mean of $x_2$. To test for 2, you should conduct the hypothesis test that $\beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$.

> when I test whether beta_x1=0, that is also not rejected.

This is a test of 1. which indicates that you cannot reject that there is no (mean) effect for the subgroup where $x_2 = 0$.

**Remark 1**: Hypothesis tests are a bit *strange* in the sense that they can contradict each other. For example it is possible that you do not reject $\beta_1 = 0$ and $\beta_2 = 0$ but you do reject $\beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$.

**Remark 2**: related to this, notice that the tests are not independent. So if you test all three hypothesis, you have the *mutliple testing* issue (cfr [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem)) in the sense that the probability of rejecting at least one of the three is (likely) bigger than the nominal value of the test.